# Hide a message in an image - Cops

Tags: cops-and-robbers, steganography

[Robbers thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223160/45613)

Your task is to create a method for hiding information in an image. You will post three encoded messages of your choice (keep them classy), each with its associated image. Reveal the messages for the first two images and do not reveal the third. Robbers have the task of determining what your third hidden message is, along with an explanation of how your system works.

### Rules and Scoring

- Any data aside from the image required to make your algorithm work must be revealed openly and be constant across all possible message encodings.

  - For example, you may have a book cipher referencing The Great Gatsby (which is in the public domain as of January 1, 2021) as long as you link to the exact text required to make your system work.
  - RNG and Cryptographic algorithms are allowed under this caveat. Robbers should not be required to guess cryptographic secrets such as keys, hashes, salts, or initial seeds, as that easily makes cracking any given challenge infeasible. That would ruin the fun.
  - Do not share irrelevant information, e.g. "It's one of these 100 books" when you only use 1, or revealing a key which you don't use at all in your system, etc...
- Data may not be hidden entirely in image metadata; you must incorporate at least one bit of one pixel in your system of encoding.
- The encoded messages must be in English.
- The encoded message does not need to be easily machine-readable (though it's perfectly acceptable if it is), but must be reasonably legible as rendered.

  - For example, you could have the message manifest itself as a rendering in Arial. Or perhaps it renders as a figlet font in ascii art.
  - The hidden message being rendered in something like Wingdings would be unacceptable, however. Using a frilly gothic font is probably pushing it.
- You may encode the message as audio as long as it is intelligible to a fluent English speaker.
- The encoded message should always be in the same format. So for example, using a rendered hidden text image for one message, an audio recording for the second, and plain text for the third, would not be allowed.
- Data required to render the message as an image or audio is not considered part of the data required to make your algorithm work (which you would otherwise need to reveal)
- A rendered encoding must be intelligible as-is and not require additional processing, e.g. a ROT13 cipher.
- You may post more than 3 hidden messages if you wish, but keep in mind this is probably a disadvantage.
- You may only encode one message in the image. No (intentional) decoy messages.
- It's not required per-se that the images hiding your messages look like anything (e.g. cats, dinosaurs, scenic vistas, etc...), but you're no fun if they look like random noise and I will be downvoting any post that uses examples that do.

You will score 1 point if your system remains uncracked after 7 days.

Comment: Needing both an ASCII art as well as an image in combination to encode the message strikes me as overly complicated. I think this challenge would be more accessible if it were just one or the other.

Comment: "Data hidden in the image must be hidden in the pixel data rather than headers or how the image is encoded; your system should still work if the image is converted to another lossless format." doesn't that ruin all the interesting things and restrict us to LSB steganography? If there are 10 ways to hide information in an image, 10 ways to hide it in ASCII art and 10 ways to combine them, don't we have to try 1000 different things to win? (this question has my imaginary downvote now; it's not an actual one because an actual one would magically push it to +5 in a few minutes)

Comment: @Arnauld - yeah, that's pretty much what I had in mind.

Comment: @xnor I'm going to feel it out for a few days and remove the ascii art element if there are no submissions by monday.

Comment: @thedefault. LSB isn't the only way to hide information in pixels. One option off the top of my head is bit count parity. Another is to select specific pixels based on some key extracted from the ascii art and assemble them into a certain arrangement.

Comment: One potential problem I see with allowing data to be hidden in png metadata is that imgur might mangle it during uploads

Comment: @Beefster so how many things do we have to try to decode the image, how many things do we have to try to decode the ASCII art, and how many things do we have to try to combine the results correctly? "select specific pixels based on some key extracted from the ascii art" - can you provide an example *just for this part* that does not require hours of guessing to figure out? (and if the image does not look like random noise, the data encoded in the ASCII art will have to look like random noise, so you won't know you've guessed correctly unless you somehow figure everything else out)

Comment: Hmm... You make a compelling point. I will drop the ascii art element of this challenge. *sigh*. Another case of "it works in the sandbox, but not in main".

Comment: Might also want to restrict it to only sharing necessary information to make the cipher work, otherwise someone could just do a book cipher and say it's one of *insert 100 books here*

Comment: Does the data have to be encoded into the image in an algorithmic way? Or could I, say, hide the message as the color of every 50th pixel then hand-draw an image around them that makes them blend in?

Comment: @xnor that method would be fair game. No fancy algorithms are required.

Comment: While I doubt it will help more people be interested in the question, I think it's important that the encoded messages be long enough to justify searching for them. If someone hides extremely short words, there's not a lot to make it worth trying to crack. I think it could help to make a minimum length, and maybe use either the same message for all 3 images, or the same image for all 3 messages. If you want to try resurrecting the Q, I'd try one or more of the above.

Answer (score 7):

## RRRGGGBBB!!! [`Cracked by Unrelated String`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239965/98630)

###### Difficulty: Easy

---

### First image: `HELLO,WORLD!`

[image: Red]

### Second image: `COPS AND ROBBERS`

[image: Green]

### Third image

[image: Blue]

Title inspired by [rrrgggbbb.com](https://rrrgggbbb.com)

Comment: AFAICT, these images are pure `#f00`, `#0f0`, and `#00f`, respectively, so I don't see how a message could be encoded in the pixel data. (Note that hiding the message in image metadata isn't allowed)

Comment: @tjjfvi I can confirm the data is stored in the pixels. I can't give any more hints without pretty much giving the answer away

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239965/85334)

Comment: @alephalpha (15 chars)

Answer (score 4):

## Low difficulty

**Image 1:**

> `ABCDabcd01::::`

[image: A cat, whose name is Scully, sleeping. The image itself doesn't matter, of course.]

**Image 2:**

> `Fun fact: The practice of designing a cryptographic algorithm which itself uses cryptography to allow the designer of the algorithm to read any message is known as "kleptography"` (not relevant to this, just an interesting field that's a friend-of-a-friend of steganography)

[image: A llama, with wheels. The image itself doesn't matter, of course.]

**Image 3:**

Crack this one!

[image: A snowy field. The image itself doesn't matter, of course.]

### Hints

**Hint 1:**

> Only one color channel is relevant. Look for odd patterns.

**Hint 2:**

> Try looking at the parity of things. (You'll know what these "things" are when you see them)

**Hint 3:**

> Symmetry matters, but not necessarily the visual symmetry.

Comment: `md5sum` for these images: `4bf4130af67681416775706b9399002b` (cat), `46c897e0588c289f52864a55f5d86871` (llama), `7766488bbc2f3a849aff5d97d555791c` (snow)

Comment: Probably safe now?

Answer (score 3):

## [Cracked by Redwolf Programs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239646/100664)

[image]

Message: HI

[image]

Message: BYE

[image]

So what is this one?

I'll see what happens....

Comment: [Cracked](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239646/79857)

Answer (score 3):

## Feline Steganography

#### Image 1: `feline steganography`

[image: Image 1]

#### Image 2: `what could it be?`

[image: Image 2]

#### Image 3: ???

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Not a crack, but I think I can finally make out a cat shooting beams from its eyes and mouth in your profile picture...?

Comment: @UnrelatedString Close; those are its whiskers

Comment: Safe now (I think?)

Comment: @emanresuA Probably, yeah, but I’ll let it stick around for a little longer since it’s the holidays

Answer (score 2):

## Medium difficulty

**Image 1:**

`hello world`

[image: image one]

**Image 2:**

`llama with wheels`

[image: image two]

**Image 3:**

[image: image three]

Comment: This issafe now

Comment: @emanresuA Sadly, this is actually not possible to crack. I'm working on a new one that is.

Answer (score 2):

## Should be easy

###### Image 1:

[image: first image used]

> `This was a really astoundingly terrible idea, come to think of it`

###### Image 2:

[image: second image used]

> `posed look`

###### Image 3:

[image]

Comment: Oh, seeing your old pfp at that size I finally see how it was supposed to be Ryze originally :P

Comment: I think this is safe now

Comment: @emanresuA I'm worried this might be too far into a grey area with the no hidden keys rule, so I might post a revised version without the possibly-offending bit before claiming the point

Answer (score 2):

## The sort you'd expect

**Image 1:**

> `These are colorful for a reason!`

[image: A rainbow]

**Image 2:**

> `Stock photos FTW`

[image: Oil paints]

**Image 3:**

Crack this one!

[image: Multicolored clothes in a closet]

**Hint 1:**

> The title is a hint

**Hint 2:**

> This was inspired by emanresu A's cop

Comment: Thissis safe now

Answer (score 2):

## Medium

*Note: I had to update the images due to a problem with the encoder, be sure to redownload them if needed*

**Image 1:**

`explore the universe`

[image: Image 1]

**Image 2:**

`no transparency?`

[image: Image 2]

**Image 3:**

[image: Image 3]

**Hint 1:**

> The first pixel of the image is the only one where the green channel is important.

Answer (score 0):

## Should be easy for real this time

###### Image 1

> `This is a simplified version of my previous cop, and very directly so. I hope you can already guess at the basic principle of it, but I would strongly caution against trying to do this by eye alone.`

[image]

###### Image 2

> `In combination with salt, this liquid will give the sea a flavour of the kind of lemonade known as aigresel. It will thus be easy to remove the saline and citric particles from the water and render it drinkable, which will make it unnecessary for ships to be provisioned with barrels of water. This breaking down of sea water by the boreal liquid is a necessary preliminary to the development of new sea creatures, which will provide a host of amphibious servants to pull ships and help in fisheries, replacing the ghastly legions of sea-monsters which will be annihilated by the admixture of boreal fluid and the consequent changes in the the sea’s structure. The sudden death of all of them will rid the Ocean of these vile creatures, images of the intensity of our passions which are represented by the bloodthirsty battles of so many monsters.`
>
> `--Charles Fourier, apparently` (there's only supposed to be one newline)

[image]

###### Image 3

[image]

Hints even though it's already been a week:

> An image composed entirely of red and white of the same intensity (by some measure) could not encode a message. Replace either with yellow, and it could.

> The message is encoded in UTF-8.