# Hide a message in an image - Robbers

Tags: cops-and-robbers, steganography

[Choose a challenge from the Cops thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/223158/45613), determine the third hidden message, and describe how the system works.

Keep in mind limitations and possibilities available to Cops:

- You are not expected to guess any cryptographic secrets or additional information required to extract the hidden messages, as they should have already been included in their post.
- The hidden message will be in English
- The hidden message may be encoded as plain text, a text bitmap rendering, audio clip, or ascii art font. This encoding will be consistent across all hidden messages.
- No further processing will be required after obtaining the hidden message.
- Data is allowed to be hidden in metadata, but at least one bit of one pixel must have been used for something.

Score 1 point per cracked system.

Answer (score 7):

## [CreaZyp154](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/239893/85334)'s

I don't know the first thing about image encodings, but it looks like in each of the three images every pixel is an index into a palette containing two identical colors. Messages are encoded as transposed images in the palette indices.

Thus, the third image says `STEGANOGRAPHY`:

[image]

Comment: Correct ! it can also be viewed by changing one of the colors of the palette in GIMP (or equivalent) (window > Dockable Dialogs > Colormaps)

Answer (score 3):

## [emanresu A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/223192/79857)'s

Image 1, which encodes `HI`, can be decoded by turning it into a 32×32 square:

[image: The word "HI"]

Same with Image 2, which encodes `BYE`:

[image: The word "BYE"]

And, with Image 3:

> [image: The words "OI You!"]
>  
>  The words `OI You!`

Since all the images are 1024×1, you just need to split it into segments 32 pixels wide, and stack them on top of one another.

Here's a tool I wrote to do this: https://gist.github.com/Radvylf/b5d1bc5f39903400b243abf2041feefe